# I have trouble calling my PHP function/method

Tags: php, oop

I am having trouble calling the variable inside my class method. Variable userId won't display on screen. Below is my class and my index.php file. I want to display the userId of the user after form submission.

```
class validateLogin 
{
    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $password;

    public function __construct($aUserName,$aUserPassword) 
    {       
        $this->username = $aUserName;
        $this->password = $aUserPassword;
    }

    public function checkUser() 
    {
        $conn = new dbconnection();
        $dbh = $conn->connect();

        $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM tbluser WHERE username=:username AND password=:password");
        $query->bindParam(":username", $this->username);
        $query->bindParam(":password", $this->password);

        $query->execute();  

        $counts = $query->rowCount();       

        if($counts==1) {        
            $results = $query->fetch();
            $this->id = $results['id'];
        }
    }
    public function getUserId() {
        return $this->id;
    }       

}
```

My index.php is below (assume that the submit button has been clicked)

```
require_once 'classes/class.Database.php';
require_once 'classes/class.Validation.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {              
        $user = new validateLogin($_POST['username'],$_POST['password']);           
        echo getUserId()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constructor is not calling the:

```
checkUser();
```

You need to make the constructor do that or:

```
require_once 'classes/class.Database.php';
require_once 'classes/class.Validation.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {              
        $user = new validateLogin($_POST['username'],$_POST['password']);
        $user->checkUser();
        echo $user->getUserId();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the object

```
echo getUserId()
```

should be

```
echo $user->getUserId()
```

Comment: then `id` isn't getting set, the function is getting called fine.  and the other answer tells you how to get the `id` set.